Velleman 4.3.20 - Is my proof valid?
[Context and level: First-year undergraduate just out of calculus 1 doing intro to proofs course]
Questions:

My proof treats the variable $y$ differently from book. (If I understand correctly, I've done a 'universal instantiation' while the book does 'existential instantiation'.) Is my proof still valid?

Any other feedback about style or other proof-writing considerations?


Exercise 4.3.20 Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$. Let $B= \{X \in \mathscr{P}{(A)} \, | \, X \neq \emptyset \}$, and define a relation $S$ on $B$ as follows:
$$
S = \{(X,Y) \in B \times B \, | \, \forall x \in X \forall y \in Y (xRy) \}
$$
Prove that if $R$ is transitive, then so is $S$.
My proof. Suppose $R$ is transitive. Let $X, Y,$ and $Z \in B$. Suppose $(X,Y) \in S$ and $(Y,Z) \in S$. Let $x \in X, y \in Y$, and $z \in Z$. Since $(X,Y) \in S$ and $(Y,Z) \in S$, $xRy$ and $yRz$. Since $xRy$, $yRz$, and $R$ is transitive, it follows that $xRz$. Since $x$ and $z$ were arbitrary elements of $X$ and $Z$ respectively, we get $(X, Z) \in S$. Hence we conclude that $S$ is transitive. $\square$
Book proof. Suppose $R$ is transitive, and suppose $(X,Y) \in S$ and $(Y, Z) \in S$. To prove that $(X, Z) \in S$ we must show that $\forall x \in X \forall z \in Z (xRz)$, so let $x \in X$ and $z \in Z$ be arbitrary. Since $Y \in B$, $Y \neq \emptyset$, so we can choose $y \in Y$. Since $(X, Y) \in S$ and $(Y, Z) \in S$, by the definition of $S$ we have $xRy$ and $yRz$. But since $R$ is transitive, $xRz$, as required. $\square$
[Edit: For full context in case it's relevant, the exercise also asks why the empty set has to be excluded from the set $B$ to make this proof work. And then the book solution says the empty set had to be excluded from $B$, so that we could come up with $y \in Y$ in the proof.]

"Since $xRy$, $yRz$ , and $R$  is reflexive, it follows that $xRz$" didn't you mean to say that $R$ is transitive?

@A.Person Yes, thank you for catching that. I've edit it.

I think I misinterpreted how the book proof instantiates $y$, and when the book proof says "we can choose $y \in Y$", it is universal instantiation too.

When the book says "we can choose $y \in Y$," it is existential instantiation, not universal.  We have $Y \ne \varnothing$, which means $\exists y(y \in Y)$.  It is that existential statement that justifies introducing $y$.

@DanVelleman I see - thank you!

Your proof is correct, even though that you have to say that $Y \neq \emptyset$ as done in the book proof, because if $Y$ was empty there would not exist any element $y \in Y$ such that $xRy$ since the empty set does not have any element in it.
Also, on a more formal note, it would be nice to write a sentence like "we must show that (...) in order to prove (initial statement)".

Thank you for the feedback - much appreciated.
